# 2D matrix for labelbinarizer

Tags: feature-engineering

There is one behavior of [labelbinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]))
lb.classes_
```

The output is `array([0, 1, 2])`. Why there is a 2 there?

Answer (score 3):

I think the documentation is kind of self-explanatory here. Fit takes in array of size `n_samples` in which each element is the class of the datum or if the data point belongs to multiple classes, the input would be obviously of size `n_samples x n_classes`. That is what you gave in as input in your example. Each point can belong to any of the three classes. That is why you have `[0, 1, 2]` as number of classes. So as mentioned in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.fit) if you try

```
>> lb.transform([0, 1, 2, 0])
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]]
```

and if you try a class that is non-existent after fit like

```
>> lb.transform([0, 1, 2, 1000])
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 0]]
```

No class named `1000` exists, so multi-targeted conversion for `1000` class case is plainly `[0, 0, 0]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean you have three classes for the first code snippet? Actually I guess the documentation was so brief, I didn't understand when I read.

Comment: @Media The first code snippet is the continuation of what op has mentioned from the sklearn documentation. But either ways it has three classes.

Answer (score 2):

Because in `lb.fit` you feed in a 2-by-3 array, which means 2 samples and each sample could have at most 3 classes. Therefore, you got `0, 1, 2` here. See:

```
           class0     class1     class2
sample1      0           1            1
sample2      1           0            0
```

---

However, I think `LabelBinarizer` encoder has one character very unlike other encoders. Note that usually we put the raw form of lables into `encoder.fit()` function; for example:

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit([1, 2, 2, 6])
LabelEncoder()
>>> le.classes_
array([1, 2, 6])
```

and we expect `encoder.transform()` yield the required format for new raw labels, i.e.,

```
>>> le.transform([1, 1, 2, 6]) 
array([0, 0, 1, 2]...)
```

But for `LabelBinarizer`, I think what we put into `lb.fit()` is actually the required coding format, and the true raw label codes should be like `[[1,2], 0]`, which seems not to be format can be handled by `sklearn` since the dimension varies. Here is the paradox, in the python document, we see such an example:

```
>>> lb.transform([0, 1, 2, 1])
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

all samples in `[0,1,2,1]` are uniquely labeled, and if you tried to use `lb.transform([[1,2],2])` to indicate that the first sample is multiple-labeled, you get error. That is, your raw labels have to in the exactly same format as after being transformed by `lb`.